# Is there a direct way to "send" a file from one user to another in Linux

Tags: linux, sudo, cp, usergroups

To clarify for users who think this is a common question... I know how to use an intermediate directory with a common group to transfer a file between two users. *In my situation that intermediate file is a security risk.* Is there a ***direct*** option to share a file?

## Scenario

user A has a huge file f1.gz with group g1. This group cannot be modified for security reasons.

user A has groups g1,g2

user B has an area where they want to store that file

user B only has groups g2,g3 (so they share g2 with user A, but *not the file's group*)

Imagine in this scenario that user A can become user B via an authentication script with the `SGID` bit set for g2, so user A could actually be the sender and the (impersonated) receiver.

## Limitations

`sudo su -c` is out of the question because this transfer is part of a non-interactive script.

I can't add any groups to user A or user B.

*I can't make a directory g2-writable* because 1) user A would have access outside the script to freely modify anything in the directory, and 2) there are multiple users involved here in group g2 and I don't want a user C messing with user A's file in the g2-writable directory.

## Question

***Without having user B create a g2-writable directory where user A can drop the file, is it possible to "send" the file to user B in an efficient way? What are my options?***

## Ideas

- I've thought about using a remote database, but the file is huge and there are too many users performing the same action too quickly. I also can't expect a local database to keep running without interruption due to machine cycling (only the `NFS` remains always-available). I'm very much looking for a *direct* exchange.
- I've also thought about temporarily changing the group of the file, but that is obviously a security issue.
- I've looked at other posts with similar questions, but they don't seem to have the same limitations.
- Some sort of SCP/rsync? But, I can have a key sitting around which allows user A to become user B outside the script.

I'm totally stumped. Any thoughts?

Comment: You have a good question, but you have posted to the wrong StackEachange site. I’m voting to close this question because your question is not "Programming" related, it is more appropriate for the StackExchange sites [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/). Your question is really "How do I manage Linux user file access".

Comment: Ah! You’re right—I meant to post it on the unix exchange like my other questions. I’ll re-open it there. I would close it here myself, but it appears I don’t have a close button.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is to use a temporary directory both groups have access to, copy the file to that directory as user A, and copy from that directory as user B. Assuming they both have access to `/tmp`:

```bash
userA $ mkdir /tmp/f1
userA $ chown userA:g2 /tmp/f1
userA $ chmod 750 /tmp/f1
userA $ cp path/to/f1.gz /tmp/f1/f1.gz

userB $ cp /tmp/f1/f1.gz /path/to/destination
```

This would give group `g2` read access the file. If this is not desired, you could have userB set up the temp directory with owner `userB:g1` and permissions `660`, but that would obviously give `g1` read access to the file.

`/tmp` is not necessarily a recommended place to store this, I only recommend it if you don't have permissions to set up a directory elsewhere. `/srv` is a good alternative. `/tmp` may be faster if it is mounted in RAM, however.

In terms of direct exchange, I don't see a way to do it without giving userA access outside of the script as well.

EDIT: Another method using sockets:

```bash
userA $ mkdir /tmp/f1
userA $ chown userA:g2 /tmp/f1
userA $ chmod 750 /tmp/f1
userA $ mkfifo /tmp/f1/f1.socket
userA $ cp /path/to/f1.gz /tmp/f1/f1.socket

userB $ cp /tmp/f1/f1.socket /path/to/destination
```

This should improve performance, but there's no way to guaruntee userB is the one reading since anyone in `g2` has read perms.

Comment: Thanks for the response! As mentioned in the limitations section, I can't expose the file to the whole group (chmod 750 does that), nor can I expose the temp directory to user A. I can't trust user A to not accidentally mess with the directory outside of the running script. I'm most likely looking for a solution outside of generic file/folder permissions.

Comment: Neither user can use `chown` or `sudo` either

Comment: @szofar It wouldn't be difficult to create a custom daemon that bridges a socket only writable by userA to a socket only readable by userB, but I'm not sure that's a 'good' solution. Otherwise, I think there do exist more complex privledge systems for unix, but I've never looked into it. I don't think there's a good way to give userA access when the script is running but no access otherwise. You'd likely need a third daemon user to handle the transfer.

Comment: yeahhh that's what I'm afraid of. This is why I am also considering a DB (third "user"/party) where neither user nor any of the groups involved have control. Thanks for the thought!